# Preventing ArcPy from truncating url?

Tags: arcpy, domains

I have a script to replace links for pictures from an old folder to a new folder.

> Truncates the link to '\env.gov.ab.ca\Parks\CityWorks\Referenced\Franchere_Bay_PRA', what I want is '\\env.gov.ab.ca\Parks\CityWorks\Referenced\Franchere_Bay_PRA'

```
 import arcpy
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/vincent.law/Documents/CW/CW_Franchere_Bay_PRA.gdb"

    a2 = """def rep_field(in_fld, rep_value):
        targets = ['W:\OPERATIONS\CPI\Asset_Management\GNSS Projects\Parks Inventory\Franchere Bay PRA\FRANCHEREBAYPRA-20150804-CD~files','W:\OPERATIONS\CPI\Asset_Management\GNSS Projects\Parks Inventory\Franchere Bay PRA\FRANCHEREBAYPRA_AUG4_2015_JL~files','W:\OPERATIONS\CPI\Asset_Management\GNSS Projects\Parks Inventory\Franchere Bay PRA\FRANCHERE BAY PRA-04-08-15-TCN~files','W:\OPERATIONS\CPI\Asset_Management\GNSS Projects\Parks Inventory\Franchere Bay PRA\FRANCHERE BAY PRA_2015-08-04_CS~files']
        for targ in targets:
            in_fld = in_fld.replace(targ, rep_value)
        return in_fld"""

    a1 = """rep_field (!Picture!,'\\\env.gov.ab.ca\Parks\CityWorks\Referenced\Franchere_Bay_PRA')"""

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="Bench_and_Table", field="Picture", expression = a1, expression_type="PYTHON_9.3", code_block = a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You either have to put a r in front of the path name so that python doesn't think that the \ is a special character. Try this instead.

```
r'\\env.gov.ab.ca\Parks\CityWorks\Referenced\Franchere_Bay_PRA'
```

You could also try:

```
'//env.gov.ab.ca/Parks/CityWorks/Referenced/Franchere_Bay_PRA'
```

You can look into the os.path module as well. There's a similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network/7170008#7170008).